# Does the R and Python implementaions of random forests handle categorical variables differently?

Tags: r, categorical-data, python, random-forest

Does R and Python implementaions of Random Forest handle categorical variable differently ? `sklearn` vs. `randomForest` implementations

clue :
I've heard that R implementation looks for the best combination of categories for each split and sklearn looks for one category which provides the best split...

is it true that difference lays here ?

Comment: They are going to be fundamentally different.  [sklearn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scikit-learn), [randomForest](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/randomForest/randomForest.pdf).  The Breimann and Cutler is originally Fortran while sklearn is Python/Cython.

Comment: @EngrStudent You can code the same algorithm in different languages, yes?

Comment: @dsaxton - that sounds like the difference between theory and practice.  In theory they can be the same, but in practice there are often differences.  They can be subtle or overt.  A big one is likely the random number generation, which strongly influences performances.  The Brieman and Cutler is extensively [trademarked](https://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~breiman/RandomForests/) which means folks have to change their code in a substantial way.  It is GPL (3.0) so folks are obligated to follow those directives if it is a derivative work.

Comment: Breimann? Brieman? Breiman!

Comment: IMO this is very close to something like "How can categorical predictors be treated in random forests? What are the pros & cons of different approaches?" http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/96442/17230 might be helpful.