# how do you calculate the number of combinations recursive partitioning uses in decision trees?

Tags: random-forest, cart, combinatorics, rpart, partitioning

So I was wondering why random forests limit the levels of a variable to 32 levels, and I found an answer here :
 [R's randomForest can not handle more than 32 levels. What is workaround?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/49243/rs-randomforest-can-not-handle-more-than-32-levels-what-is-workaround)

My question is why is the solution 2^N+2 ? I thought it would be the classic combination equation of N choose K, such that if I had 32 levels of data, choosing 2 at a time to partition would yield 32=N choose 2=K producing  :

N! / K!(N-K)!
32! / 2!(30!)
=496

Comment: There are $2^n$ proper subsets of any set of $n$ elements.  Each subset corresponds to a distinct path through the tree.  Drawing a smaller tree--even $n=3$ nodes will suffice--ought to convince you this is correct.

Comment: In case anyone googles and lands on this page, I cross posted and got a very clear response here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40516770/what-does-recursive-partitioning-create-2n-combinations-from-n-levels-of-data/40517185#40517185